# How to use cmdstan in a singularity (apptainer) container?

Tags: permissions, containers, hpc, stan, singularity-container

The default install location for cmdstan is `$HOME/.cmdstan`.

In a singularity container, I can install cmdstan somewhere else (e.g., `/opt/cmdstan`).

The problem is cmdstan sometime requires writing permission during compiling models but I don’t have the permission for `/opt/cmdstan` in the singularity container.

Where should I install cmdstan in a container, and how should I solve this permission problem especially when I use HPC?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping it `/opt/cmdstan` seems a good place. As far as the writing issue goes, you have two main choices:

1. Write to the host OS

This is simplest option if you can control or know where the writing happens. Since `$PWD` is one of the [system-defined auto mount directories](https://docs.sylabs.io/guides/3.10/user-guide/bind_paths_and_mounts.html#system-defined-bind-paths), you can just write there.

If you know instead that they are written to `/opt/cmdstan/cache`, you can [explicitly mount a directory from the host OS](https://docs.sylabs.io/guides/3.10/user-guide/bind_paths_and_mounts.html#user-defined-bind-paths) with *e.g.,* `-B /scratch:/opt/cmdstan`.

This option is particularly useful if you want to have access to the generated files outside of the running container.

2. Use a tmpfs overlay

If you don't know where the files are being generated and/or don't care what they are, you can you use the [`--writable-tmpfs`](https://docs.sylabs.io/guides/3.10/user-guide/singularity_and_docker.html?highlight=writable-tmpfs#read-only-by-default) flag with your singularity command.

A limitation here is that the size of the overlay is the size of `/dev/shm` on the host OS. This can sometimes be smaller than expected (I've noticed as low as 32-64MB in some cloud VMs), which will cause the writes to fail complaining about no disk space when there is still space on the host partition.

Comment: Yes, installing cmdstan to $HOME is easy and straightforward. I have a similar problem when I use tex in a singularity container. The option -B seems very useful. Thanks!